# Magento: How to load large tables into custom db table?

Tags: magento

I have a sql installer file for my custom Magento module. It attempts to insert many thousands of rows into a custom database table but it runs out of memory and the module doesn't install.

Everything works fine if I put the table in manually with normal mysql and there is no 'memory balloon' doing it that way.

I would like my module to work as a module, without having to do anything manually on the command line. Is there any way I can break down my installer file or call some external routine to get the data in?

Comment: How many rows? Post some sample code. It's possible there is room for refactoring. I assume you've already tried increasing the memory limit before running the SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could distribute a CSV file containing the data with your module and use MySQL's LOAD DATA command to load the data into the table you create in your upgrade script.

Maybe something like:

```
$db = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$filename = Mage::getBaseDir('code').'/local/Your/Module/sql/your_module_setup/foo.csv';
$sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$filename."' INTO TABLE foo FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' lines terminated by '\r\n'";
$db->query($sql);
```

You can, of course, run further queries if you need to process the data somehow.

Comment: Thankyou very much for that - I haven't tried it yet, but I think you have put together everything I need to get my module to install.

Answer (score 0):

You can split up creating table and inserts in different upgrade scripts.